# add validation for first and last name in checkout billing address

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, validation

I would like to add alphabet validation for first and last name field in onepage checkout billing section.

But unable to find the template being loaded for this section. Other fields are being loaded from

`base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

How to find the template for first and last name fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my magento instalation the template for first name and last name, in checkout, is 
`template/customer/widget/name.phtml`

It is added in `template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml` as

```
`<li class="fields"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getAddress()->getFirstname() ? $this->getAddress() : $this->getQuote()->getCustomer())->setForceUseCustomerRequiredAttributes(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn())->setFieldIdFormat('billing:%s')->setFieldNameFormat('billing[%s]')->toHtml() ?></li>`
```

under

```
<li id="billing-new-address-form"...>
```

But try to activate template path hints and you will see which template is responsible to rendering this fields.

Comment: Great ! good luck !